MongoDb to Pomelo Mysql Repository Pattern
I am following a tutorial where Mongo DB is being used. However, I want to convert it to Mysql. The author is using Repository pattern. Below is the link to the tutorial;
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByYyk8eMG6c
Specific classes that I am looking into to convert are;
MongoRespository.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace Play.Common.MongoDB
{

    public class MongoRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : IEntity
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<T> dbCollection;
        private readonly FilterDefinitionBuilder<T> filterBuilder = Builders<T>.Filter;

        public MongoRepository(IMongoDatabase database, string collectionName)
        {
            dbCollection = database.GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
        }

        public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<T>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            return await dbCollection.Find(filterBuilder.Empty).ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<T>> GetAllAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
        {
            return await dbCollection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
        }        

        public async Task<T> GetAsync(Guid id)
        {
            FilterDefinition<T> filter = filterBuilder.Eq(entity => entity.Id, id);
            return await dbCollection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        public async Task<T> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
        {
            return await dbCollection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }        

        public async Task CreateAsync(T entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
            }

            await dbCollection.InsertOneAsync(entity);
        }

        public async Task UpdateAsync(T entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
            }

            FilterDefinition<T> filter = filterBuilder.Eq(existingEntity => existingEntity.Id, entity.Id);
            await dbCollection.ReplaceOneAsync(filter, entity);
        }

        public async Task RemoveAsync(Guid id)
        {
            FilterDefinition<T> filter = filterBuilder.Eq(entity => entity.Id, id);
            await dbCollection.DeleteOneAsync(filter);
        }
    }
}

Extensions.cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using Play.Common.Settings;

namespace Play.Common.MongoDB
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddMongo(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new GuidSerializer(BsonType.String));
            BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new DateTimeOffsetSerializer(BsonType.String));

            services.AddSingleton(serviceProvider =>
            {
                var configuration = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>();
                var serviceSettings = configuration.GetSection(nameof(ServiceSettings)).Get<ServiceSettings>();
                var mongoDbSettings = configuration.GetSection(nameof(MongoDbSettings)).Get<MongoDbSettings>();
                var mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoDbSettings.ConnectionString);
                return mongoClient.GetDatabase(serviceSettings.ServiceName);
            });

            return services;
        }

        public static IServiceCollection AddMongoRepository<T>(this IServiceCollection services, string collectionName)
            where T : IEntity
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IRepository<T>>(serviceProvider =>
            {
                var database = serviceProvider.GetService<IMongoDatabase>();
                return new MongoRepository<T>(database, collectionName);
            });

            return services;
        }
    }
}

I have tried converting it and use a DbContext in Extensions class, however, I am unable to translate generic behavior in Extensions as well as MongoRepository classes. Below is the code;
I am using

Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

Extensions.cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using TransactPulse.Common.Settings;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace TransactPulse.Common.MysqlDB
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddMysql(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<MysqlDbContext>((serviceProvider, dbContextOptions) =>
            {
                var configuration = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>() ?? throw new Exception($"{nameof(IConfiguration)} is not configured.");
                
                var serviceSettings = configuration.GetSection(nameof(ServiceSettings)).Get<ServiceSettings>() 
                                                ?? throw new Exception($"{nameof(ServiceSettings)} is not configured.");
                var mysqlDbSettings = configuration.GetSection(nameof(MysqlDbSettings)).Get<MysqlDbSettings>() 
                                                ?? throw new Exception($"{nameof(MysqlDbSettings)} is not configured.");
                dbContextOptions.UseMySql(
                        $"{mysqlDbSettings.ConnectionString} database={serviceSettings.ServiceName}",
                        ServerVersion.AutoDetect(mysqlDbSettings.ConnectionString)
                )
                // The following three options help with debugging, but should
                // be changed or removed for production.
                .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information)
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
            });
            return services;
        }

        public static IServiceCollection AddMysqlRepository<T>(this IServiceCollection services, string collectionName)
            where T : IEntity
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IRepository<T>>(serviceProvider =>
            {
                var database = serviceProvider.GetService<MysqlDbContext<T>>();
                
                return new MysqlRepository<T>(database, collectionName);
            });

            return services;
        }
    }
}

MysqlRepository.cs
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;

namespace TransactPulse.Common.MysqlDB
{

    public class MysqlRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : IEntity
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<T> dbCollection;
        //private readonly FilterDefinitionBuilder<T> filterBuilder = Builders<T>.Filter;
        private MysqlDbContext<T> _context;
        public MysqlRepository(MysqlDbContext<T> database, string collectionName)
        {
            // dbCollection = database.Set<IEntity>(collectionName).;
            //dbCollection = database.GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
        }

        public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<T>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            return null;
            //return await dbCollection.Find(filterBuilder.Empty).ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<T>> GetAllAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
        {
            return null;
            //return await dbCollection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
        }        

        public async Task<T> GetAsync(Guid id)
        {
            return default(T);
            // FilterDefinition<T> filter = filterBuilder.Eq(entity => entity.Id, id);
            // return await dbCollection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        public async Task<T> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
        {
            return default(T);
            //return await dbCollection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }        

        public async Task CreateAsync(T entity)
        {
            // if (entity == null)
            // {
            //     throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
            // }

            // await dbCollection.InsertOneAsync(entity);
        }

        public async Task UpdateAsync(T entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
            }

            // FilterDefinition<T> filter = filterBuilder.Eq(existingEntity => existingEntity.Id, entity.Id);
            // await dbCollection.ReplaceOneAsync(filter, entity);
        }

        public async Task RemoveAsync(Guid id)
        {
            // FilterDefinition<T> filter = filterBuilder.Eq(entity => entity.Id, id);
            // await dbCollection.DeleteOneAsync(filter);
        }
    }
}

